# How install PHP's MongoDB driver — "pecl install mongo" fails

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

How do I install PHP's MongoDB client driver?

I've done this already:

```
  $ sudo aptitude install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear make
```

But the next step fails:

```
  $ sudo pecl install mongo
  No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongo"
  install failed
```

When I have a look at http://pecl.php.net/mongo, I find listed many versions of the Mongo driver. Am I supposed to include a version number or something? However all installation instructions I've found simply state that one use `sudo pecl install mongo` and nothing else. — How do I install the Mongo driver?

Some details:

1. OS: Linux Mint 16, which is based on Ubuntu.
2. `pecl list-channels` says:

   ```
    Registered Channels:
    Channel      Alias   Summary
    doc.php.net  phpdocs PHP Documentation Team
    pear.php.net pear    PHP Extension and Application
                         Repository
    pecl.php.net pecl    PHP Extension Community Library
    __uri        __uri   Pseudo-channel for static packages
   ```

Comment: [Here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/chisimba-dev/vxgl4YeL-Z0/kUigkhxskogJ) someone said *"go to pecl.php.net and see what the latest release is and install that"* but isn't that what I'm doing already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how locked into the pecl method you are, but I recently compiled the [driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver). This was on an ubuntu server. It installs the .so and all you have to do is just add "extension=mongo.so" to the php.ini files.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked. I installed this exact version: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/tree/1.4.5

Comment: PECL does nothing else than download, configure and compile the source, well. This is not an answer to the question, why PECL download fails.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Assuming of course that you installed php, etc. via apt-get as well (or synapic, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to create a working Docker container for a Laravel app. The following worked for me:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

I found this referenced in the [PHP docs comments](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php).

Answer (score 0):

**In Ubuntu 20.04, php-mongodb is outdated and you'll need the PECL method to install the latest version of MongoDB.**

First, install the php-pear and php-dev plugin

```
sudo apt install php-dev php-pear
```

Then

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```